# How to yield better AUC score?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-mining, predictive-modeling, grid-search

I have a dataset with 5K records and 60 features focused on binary classification. Class proportion is 33:67

Currently I am trying to increase the performance of my model which is stuck at F1-score of 89% (majority) and 75% (minority) class and AUC of 80%.

I tried Gridsearchcv and feature engineering. Though I don't explicity call out the best parameters on Gridsearch below, I guess when I fit, it takes the best parameters only. But nothing seems to help.

Does this mean my data has issues? When I mean issue, I am not talking about missing values. I mean the way the data was extracted. Can it be data entry issues?

This is what I tried for gridsearchcv. Am I doing it right?

```
import xgboost as xgb
parameters_xgb = {
    'learning_rate': (0.1,0.01,0.05,0.5,0.3,1),
    'n_estimators': (100,200,500,1000),
    'max_depth':(5,10,20),}
xg_clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()
xgb_clf_gv = GridSearchCV(xg_clf,parameters_xgb,cv=5)  # using cross validation with best hyperparameters
xgb_clf_op = xgb_clf_gv.fit(X_train_std,y_train)
y_pred = xgb_clf_op.predict(X_test_std)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
print(cm)
print("Accuracy is ", accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
```

I also tried `catboost` and `gb`. The AUC is only around 80-82% throughout in test data.

Comment: 6*4*3*5=360 runs of XGBoost and so strange combinations of hyperparameters! I am almost sure, that using simple split train/valid 0.8/0.2, typical set of parameters, e.i. eta=0.02, max_depth=8, subsample=0.75, colsample_bytree=0.85, tuning your imbalanced dataset: scale_pos_weight=0.5, base_score=0.333, and setting big num_round=10000 but with early_stopping_rounds=100 (most impostant thing), your 1 run XGBoost will stop close to 1452;) round and give results being in TOP5 of your gridsearch results. Really, first try to find a good set of hyperparameters manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Performance increase with hyperparameter optimization]

I would not necessarily call it data issues. There is always some threshold that you just can not surpass, depending on the dataset ofcourse. Generally feature engineering and understanding the data will yield much greater increases than just hyp.par. optimization, which as you can see from the picture, yields often marginal increases (there is a case where its worst than default parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Why is 80% bad?  Is there precedence to suggest you would expect higher?  I have ideas at 60% that return millions of $. Maybe not a perfect model but one must not always expect perfect separation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Upvoted. I have an imbalanced class and F1-score is around 70-77. Is it decent?

Comment: class proportion is 33:67 and using this as is without re-sampling, I get an F1-score of 70-77. When I undersample the majority class (becomes a balanced data), I get an F1-score of 80%.